# this.something is undefined inside component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, websocket, redux

I was making a crypto ticker on react native.

Inside that crypto ticker, I am using Redux to manage state. Here is the relevant code:

```
class cryptoTicker extends Component { 

componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchCoin()
  }

  //Socket.io 
  componentWillUpdate() {

    var socket = openSocket('https://coincap.io');
    var updateCoinData = this.props.cryptoLoaded; 
    socket.on('trades', (tradeMsg) => {  
     for (let i=0; i<100; i++) {
       console.log(i)
      console.log("this is Update data", updateCoinData[0]["short"])
      console.log("this is socket data", tradeMsg.coin)
       if ( updateCoinData[i]["short"] === tradeMsg.coin ) {
         console.log("yolo")
       }   
     }
    })

  }

  render() {

  //Update State from websocket   
  var CryptoData = this.props.cryptoLoaded;
  let displayCrypto = CryptoData.map(el => {
    console.log(el)
    return (<CoinCard
       key={el["long"]}
       coinShortName = {el["short"]}
       coinName = {el["long"]}
       coinPrice = {el["price"].toFixed(2)}
       marketCap = {el["mktcap"]}
       percentChange = {el["perc"]}
       coinImage = {"https://coincap.io/images/coins/" + el['long'] + ".png"}
      />
    )

  })
```

Here `this.props.cryptoLoaded;` is coming from redux.

In this code, inside componentWillUpdated() it throws an error saying  (somewhere here) `console.log("this is Update data", updateCoinData[0]["short"])` that it is undefined.

Since `ComponentWillUpdate()` comes after render, I am guessing it to have already loaded all the data (it is working fine render).

So two questions, what am I doing wrong here? and does redux fetches data every-time I do `this.props.cryptoLoaded` ?

**[Update:]** Github repository for the same -> https://github.com/irohitb/React-native-crpto-ticker

Comment: `componentWillUpdate(props) {`

Comment: `componentWillMount` and `componentWillUpdate` are both deprecated ([blog post on why](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html)), and will be removed in a future version of react. Try using `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: @kingdaro they are removed in react 17? i am using react 16 so I guess that shouldn't be the issue?

Comment: @zerkms Why would we need to send props in argument? Anyway, I tried it but same error. I have updated the post with my github repository for the same. In case you or anyone is able to find what I could be doing wrong in there :)

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that `componentDidUpdate` updates _after_ render instead of before, which might have been the issue, but maybe not. Maybe you just need to check if `updateCoinData[0]` exists before trying to get a property off of it

Comment: @kingdaro the websocket is responsible to update things after they have been rendered in UI. So my intent is to render things into UI, start websocket, change the previous value with the new value, store it in redux and then render it again in UI. (This might be vague or stupid/faulty way) but this is how I was thinking about updating the elements in UI

Comment: Alright, so if you want to start the websocket _after_ rendering, either `componentDidMount` or `componentDidUpdate` is what you want. The `*Will*` hooks are performed _before_ rendering. But, that's unrelated to the issue I think. Try `if (updateCoinData && updateCoinData[0])` or something